Using managed identity to connect on-premises console application to Azure SQL Server
I have an on-premises console application through which I am accessing Azure SQL Server. Currently I am using the user name/password connection string to connect to Azure SQL.
I would like to use managed identity to connect to Azure SQL from the on-premises console application.
Please let me know if it is possible and how it can be done.

Please read [ask], and then edit to provide a [mcve]. As written, there's no programming question (actually no detail at all - just a requirement).

You can not use managed identity in local, which only can be used in resources running in Azure, typical resources: vm, automation account, etc.

According to this

You cannot use Managed Identity (both system assigned and user assigned) outside of Azure. They can only be used with resources running in Azure.

So, it is not possible to connect Azure SQL database to on-premises console app with managed identity authentication. Alternatively, you can use Azure active directory interactive. So, you can use below connection sting:
Server=tcp:<serverNmae>.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=<databaseName>;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=<ADId>;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Authentication=\"Active Directory Interactive\";

Here is the complete code:
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;

string connectionString = "Server=tcp:<serverName>.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=<databaseName>;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=<ADId>;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Authentication=\"Active Directory Interactive\";";

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();

    string query = "SELECT * FROM <tableName>";
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
    {
        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                int studentId = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("Id"));
                string Name = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Name"));
                Console.WriteLine($"StudentID: {studentId}, Name: {Name}");
                     
                }
        }
    }
}

It will open browser for authentication for the first time. after that it will connect automatically after connecting. The database is connected successfully as shown below:

Along with that you can use service principle authentication to connect Azure SQL database.

The question is completely off-topic: it's just a "how can I do it" - there is no detail at all. And what you posted doesn't answer any specific question. Please stop posting custom solutions like this for questions that have zero detail (a [mcve]).

In this case I would go with a Service Principal instead.
